# How to aggregate/Sum multiple CPU cores to get one CPU metric in grafana?

Tags: centos7, grafana, graphite, health-monitoring, collectd

Is there a way to aggregate across metrics/metric-names? For example, on a four core system, you have the following metric-names:

cpu.0.system
cpu.1.system
cpu.2.system
cpu.3.system

I would like to SUM(cpu.*.system) to get the aggregated cpu.system.total.

Is there a way to accomplish this with the current Grafana-graphite query-editor?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got one other solution as described below:

Edited `vi /opt/collectd/etc/collectd.conf` file.

Uncomment LoadPlugin aggregation.

```
LoadPlugin aggregation
<Plugin aggregation>
  <Aggregation>
    #Host "unspecified"
    Plugin "cpu"
    #PluginInstance "unspecified"
    Type "cpu"
    #TypeInstance "unspecified"

    GroupBy "Host"
    GroupBy "TypeInstance"

#    CalculateNum false
#    CalculateSum false
    CalculateAverage true
#    CalculateMinimum false
#    CalculateMaximum false
#    CalculateStddev false
  </Aggregation>
</Plugin>
```

And restarted the collecd services.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
alias(sumSeries(cpu.*.system),'Total CPU')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using only build-in Grafana functions

```
1-sum(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[20s]))/8
```

Grafana will calculate average CPU usage over last 20 seconds.

**IMPORTANT**
Change last number (*"/8"* in example above), to match number of cores on your monitored instance and *"20s"* to whatever time interval you wish.

then change graph's display unit to *percent 0.0-1.0*